# Python/PHP - Downloading and installing AWS API

Tags: php, python

Is there a way to dynamically download and install a package like AWS API from a PHP or Python script at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not at runtime - this would make no sense due to the overheads involved and the risk of the download failing.